# Bootstrap CSS: div with image is overlapping div with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following four inner `div` container (small picture - text - small picture - text):

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p class="description">
            Some ... long ... text
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p class="description">
            Some ... long ... text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `CSS` for `components-circle` and `inner-component`:

```
.components-circle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 115px;
  width: 115px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #e0e0eb;
}
.inner-component {
  background: url(http://...) no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 15px;
}
```

The problem is, that `components-circle` and `inner-component` are overlapping the text which is on the right side of them when I resize the browser, that means the template is not responsive.

How could I insert a line break when the browser is resized or make `components-circle` and `inner-component` responsive, so that they do not overlap the corrsponding text on the right side?

Comment: You're using static widths in a responsive frame. Set the width to a `%` and the height should keep to the constraints.

Comment: You can add one bootstrap class to two columns like [https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSSB6WJIE42Y]

Comment: Also, You have small size `sm` rows/columns inside of a medium size `md` column. that will cause issues as well.

Comment: @Gezzasa: I can not alter the `width` as this is a round circle, then the design gets broken - also I changed to `col-sm-12` (no result). Thank you.

Comment: @chevallier images will keep to constraints if you edit the width only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using row class so just setting the `width` of `components-circle` to `100%` (rather than making it static) will work (as bootstrap will handle rest of the responsive stuff).

To keep the aspect ratio of height-width you have to remove `height` from `components-circle` and use `padding-top`. Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp) to see how it works. (`padding-top: 100%` gives 1:1 aspect ratio)

Open the below snippet in full-page view and resize to see the effect :)

Though there can be other methods to achieve the same, IMO this one is quite simple and understandable.

```css
.components-circle {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0eb;
  }
  .inner-component {
    background: url(https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eiMAAOSwH3haAlKl/s-l300.png) no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p class="description">
                Some ... long ... text
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p class="description">
                Some ... long ... text
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update:** To keep the inner image at the centre during resize, you have to set it's position to `0px 0px` (which is default) and add `background-size: contain` to the inner-component. This will scale the image to fit the parent. See the updated snippet above!

Comment: Unfortunately I can not alter the `width` as this is a round circle, then the design gets broken.

Comment: Yeah that's why I mentioned method to keep `aspect-ratio 1:1`, that will keep the circle round, what's the issue then ?

Comment: +1 - you were right, my fault. BUT: My background image does not stay at the exact center of the circle anymore - it moves to different positions when I resize the browser. So if you help me to make the background image stay always in the center of the circle, this is going to be the accepted answer :)

Comment: @chevallier I have updated the answer and code snippet, see the `update` at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the content of the "col-sm-12" div overlapping the content of the page, or the text next to the image that is overlapping?
Anyway, you can fix both of these issues in this way, using a "container" or "row" div and adding a css for page resizing.

```css
.components-circle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 115px;
  width: 115px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #e0e0eb;
}
.inner-component {
  background: url(http://...) no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 15px;
}

.center-text{
  text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 765px) {
  .center-text{
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2">
       <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 center-text">
       <h3>Title</h3>
       <p class="description">
         Some ... long ... text
       </p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">
       <div class="components-circle inner-component"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 center-text">
       <h3>Title</h3>
       <p class="description">
         Some ... long ... text
       </p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for that, I did not mention it, but I'm using a container `<div class="container">` to wrap everything already. So it does not help me :( Same with `text-align: left (or center);`

Comment: It's overlapping only the content of the text.

Comment: Are you using other classes besides these? Could you send a printscreen so I can check exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

To make a breakpoint that is hidden on larger viewports, you can use these CSS classes with the line break:

`.d-md-none` To make it invisible on anything larger than `md` sized screens.

`.d-sm-none` To hide it on anything larger than `sm` sized screens.

You may also need to put the `row` inside a `container`.

This is what it would look like: `<br class="d-md-none">`

If you want a line break without using a `<br>` element, check out [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/).

Comment: That's a cool tip, thanks, but I prefer to solve it with CSS only instead of using a `<br>` element.